# Python code not working properly

Tags: python

I've made a code to calculate the resistance in a circuit. It considers each change between 'in series' and 'in parallel' to be a 'part', then is given the number of parts, number of resistors for each part, and resistance of each resistor.

```
def resistance():
    p = int(input('Enter number of parts. One "part" is a resistor or sequence of resistors that are in parallel while the rest are in series, or vice versa.'))
    for x in range(1, p):
        n = input('Enter number of resistors in part' + x)
        for y in range(1, n):
            w = input('Enter the resistance of resistor #' + y)
            q.append(w)
        t = str(input('In series or parallel? Enter S for series, P for parallel.'))
        if t == 'S':
            for z in range(1, len(q)):
                s += q[z-1]
        elif t == 'P':
            for v in range(1, len(q)):
                s += (1/q[z-1])
        q = []
    return s
```

The problem is, whenever I run it, it takes in 'p', then gives the following error:

local variable 's' referenced before assignment

When I set s = 0 before the first loop, it just takes in 'p' then returns 0.

Can anyone tell me where this is going wrong?

EDIT: The above problem has been solved, but now there's a new one. The code is as follows:

```
def resistance():
s = 0
q = []
p = int(input('Enter number of parts. One "part" is a resistor or sequence of resistors that are in parallel while the rest are in series, or vice versa. '))
p += 1
for x in range(1, p):
    n = int(input('Enter number of resistors in part ' + str(x) + ':'))
    n += 1
    for y in range(1, n):
        w = input('Enter the resistance of resistor #' + str(y) + ', in ohms:')
        q.append(w)
    t = str(input('In series or parallel? Enter S for series, P for parallel. '))
    if t == 'S':
        for z in range(1, len(q)+1):
            s += int(q[z-1])
    elif t == 'P':
        for v in range(1, len(q)+1):
            s += int(1/int(q[z-1]))
    q = []
return s
```

It works in series, but in parallel it says:  - although I did almost the same thing with the 'in series' part and there was no error there. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try printing `len(q)` in one of your `if/elif` conditions and then selecting that condition. You need the `s=0` -- that's why you're getting the `UnboundLocalError`. This would be easier if you would give your variables better names. Where is `q` coming from? It's not set in the code you've posted.

Comment: It doesn't _just_ take in `p`. It also throws `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects` at line 4. Is there any `try-catch` around it?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you need to change a few things, first initialize a variable `s=0`and the list q=[]. With the inputs it is trying to add the string 'enter ...' and the integer `x,y`, if you want it to add two integers define `n` as

`n = input('input number')+x`, so the results is two added integers. Also when you do the input for series or parallel you will get an error that says S not defined or P not defined, you can remedy this with raw_input instead and S or P input will be converted to a string. Here is the code:

```
def resistance():
    s = 0
    q = []
    p = int(input('Enter number of parts. One "part" is a resistor or sequence of resistors that are in parallel while the rest are in series, or vice versa. '))
    for x in range(1, p):
        n = input('Enter number of resistors in part ')+x
        for y in range(1, n):
            w = float(input('Enter the resistance of resistor # '))+y
            q.append(w)
        t = raw_input('In series or parallel? Enter S for series, P for parallel. ')
        if t == 'S':
            for z in range(1, len(q)):
                s += q[z-1]
        elif t == 'P':
            for v in range(1, len(q)):
                s += (1/q[v-1])
        q = []
    return s

def test():
   print resistance()
if __name__=='__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: It's now giving me the following error:                                        n = input('Enter number of resistors in part ')+x
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Comment: Try, int(input('...'))+x. What version of python are you using? Check using import sys then sys.version

Comment: I'm using Python 3.3, and I found the code that worked; it's int(input('Enter number of resistors in part ' + str(x) + ':'))

Comment: The code now works for 'in series', but not in parallel. What I have now can be seen in the main question.

Comment: I see whats going wrong. I apologize I didn't check the P part but the elif statement says for v in .... and its referencing z which is not defined. Change the z to v. Ill do so in the code I provided.

Comment: I also added float to the value of w

Comment: Great! If u want and this helped please consider accepting my answer :)